# segmentation fault Segfault python extension in c++

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, garbage-collection, python-extensions

This extension is used to search data in a linked list and return it as a nested tuple of lists.[(ele1,ele2,),...]

However  when the program runs for a period of time, segment fault will occur. I know that there might be something I'm missing with python memory management, but it's not clear to me exactly where the problem is.

header file:

```cpp
#include "Python.h"
#define  PY_EXTENSION_H
#ifndef TESTFORSCORE_MAIN_H
#define TESTFORSCORE_MAIN_H
#define MAX(a,b) a<b?b:a
#define MIN(a,b) a<b?a:b
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef struct{
    char* content;
    int content_len;
    int features_len;
    byte* features;
    long id;
}NODE;

typedef struct LISTNODE{
    LISTNODE* next;
    NODE* node;
}LISTNODE;

extern "C"{
static PyObject *compare(byte* features1,byte* features2,int min);
static PyObject *init_map(byte* features,int features_len,char* content ,int content_len,long id);
static PyObject *get_list_size(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
static PyObject *search(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
}
#endif
```

cpp

```cpp
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include "example.h"


static LISTNODE *head_of_map=(LISTNODE*) PyMem_RawMalloc(sizeof(LISTNODE));
LISTNODE *current_head=head_of_map;
long COUNTER=0;
static PyObject *get_list_size(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("l", COUNTER);
}
static PyObject *init_map(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){//
    PyObject  *obj1,*obj2;
    int len1,len2;
    long activity;
    byte *features,*tmp_b;
    char *content,*tmp_c;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"SSiiL", &obj1,&obj2,&len1,&len2,&activity)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    features=(byte *) PyBytes_AsString(obj1);
    content=PyBytes_AsString(obj2);

    LISTNODE *list_node=(LISTNODE*) PyMem_RawMalloc(sizeof(LISTNODE));
    NODE *node=(NODE*) PyMem_RawMalloc(sizeof(NODE));
    tmp_b=(byte *) PyMem_RawMalloc(sizeof(byte)*len1);
    tmp_c=(char *) PyMem_RawMalloc(sizeof(char)*len2);
    memcpy(tmp_b,features,len1);
    memcpy(tmp_c,content,len2);
    node->features=tmp_b;
    node->content=tmp_c;
    node->features_len=len1;
    node->content_len=len2;
    node->id=activity;
    list_node->node=node;
    current_head->next=list_node;
    current_head=current_head->next;
    COUNTER+=1;
    // err maybe here
    //Py_DecRef(obj1);
    //Py_DecRef(obj2);
    PyMem_FREE(tmp_b);
    PyMem_Free(tmp_c);
    return Py_BuildValue("b",0);
}

static double _compare(byte* features1,byte* features2,int min){
    //do something ...
    return   0.3;
}
static PyObject *search(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){//(byte* features,char *content,int features_len,int content_len,double threshold,int _idx){

    PyObject *obj1,*obj2,*tuple,*content,*matched_content,*score1,*_id,*matched_id, *lis= PyList_New(0);
    byte* features;
    char *c_content,*tmp_content,*tmp_matched;
    int content_len,length ,idx;
    double  threshold,score;
    LISTNODE *p = head_of_map;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"SSiidi", &obj1,&obj2,&length,&content_len,&threshold,&idx)) {

        return NULL;
    }
    features = (unsigned  char*)PyBytes_AsString(obj1);
    c_content = PyBytes_AsString(obj2);
//    Py_DecRef(obj1);
//    Py_DecRef(obj2);
    p=p->next;
    int counter=0;
    while (p!=NULL){
        counter+=1;
//      compare here
        score =0.3;
        if(score>threshold){
            //if(counter>1000) break;
            tuple      = PyTuple_New(5);
            score1     = Py_BuildValue("d",score);
            _id        = Py_BuildValue("b",idx);
            matched_id = Py_BuildValue("l",p->node->id);

            tmp_content = (char*)PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(char)*content_len);
            if (tmp_content == NULL)
                return PyErr_NoMemory();
            memcpy(tmp_content,c_content,content_len);
            content = Py_BuildValue("y#",tmp_content,(Py_ssize_t) sizeof(char)*content_len);

            tmp_matched=(char*) PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(char)*p->node->content_len);
            if (tmp_matched == NULL)
                return PyErr_NoMemory();
            memcpy(tmp_matched,p->node->content, p->node->content_len);
            matched_content = Py_BuildValue("y#",tmp_matched,(Py_ssize_t) sizeof(char)*p->node->content_len);

            PyTuple_SetItem(tuple,0,_id);
            PyTuple_SetItem(tuple,1,matched_id);
            PyTuple_SetItem(tuple,2,score1);
            PyTuple_SetItem(tuple,3,content);
            PyTuple_SetItem(tuple,4,matched_content);

            PyList_Append(lis,tuple);
            Py_DecRef(tuple);

            PyMem_Free(tmp_content);
            PyMem_Free(tmp_matched);
        }
        p=p->next;
    }

    if (PyErr_Occurred()){
        Py_DECREF(lis);
        return NULL ;
    }
    return lis;
}
static PyMethodDef exampleMethods[] = {
        {"get_list_size", get_list_size, METH_VARARGS, "example"},
        {"compare",compare,METH_VARARGS,"example"},
        {"init_map",init_map,METH_VARARGS,"example"},
        {"destory",destory,METH_VARARGS,""},
        {"search",search,METH_VARARGS,"example"},
        { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef ptexamplemodule = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "example",           /* name of module */
        "A module that imports an API",  /* Doc string (may be NULL) */
        -1,                 /* Size of per-interpreter state or -1 */
        exampleMethods       /* Method table */
};
/* Module initialization function */
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_example(void) {
    PyObject *m;

    m = PyModule_Create(&ptexamplemodule);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Import sample, loading its API functions */
    return m;
}
int main() {
return 0;
}
```

setup file

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='example',
      ext_modules=[
          Extension('example',
                    ['example.cpp'],
                    include_dirs = [],  # May need pysample.h directory
                    )
      ],
      version="0.0.1"
      )
```

test file

```py
import example
import random
import time
import faulthandler
 
faulthandler.enable()
lis=[(b'\xd3\nR\x952\xbf\x8e\xeb[\xdc\xe8\xfb\xcb\x9f\xb4\xd2', b'\x856\x96\xda\xe4H_\xf9\xb3\x95\xff\xda\xc9\x05\x17\xd5'), (b'!\xdf\xc1\xc20h\xc3#\x8f\x8a\xd3\x92\xc9}\x1b\x08', b'\xa3\x03m\xd3\x96\x01\xb2\xe0\xfcOg\x87\xfa\xadA\x89'), (b'Fu\xe6\x97=\xb9\x88S\xe4Q\xc06\x9f[\x84J', b'`9\xf2- \x89\xc63?\xe3=\xf9o\x9b\xe4\x8e'), (b'\x95b\x1f\xba\x90\xfa\xe9j#\xd4\x12x\xc3\x93#\x1c', b'8f\xc4\xeb\xef\x95\xe8\x81\xec\xed1\x00j\xc2\xd2j'), (b'\xf9\x8bUk"\xa2y\xfbHI\x08\xf6\x03\xd3Ye', b'\xdf\xdb\xb6\x87\xf3\x05-p\x80%8\x8cd[43'), (b'\xee\x92\xcf\xb5\xd7\x05j\x92\xa2\x1c\xf7a.[\x05\x86', b'Y\x00|\x02\xa1\xb1wI\x08\xb3\xfc\xfc\xc7\xf5db'), (b"\x9d\xe0&\\~\xbf\xaf`\xae\xc2?'B\xfa\x95\x86", b'FL\xe3\xbb\x18\xeef\x08%\xe1\xc8,\xe3J=\xd5'), (b'\xe1\xfb\xc9n\x89\x1d\x9a\x9d\xe9\x1a\x9c\xde\xcd\xce\xbd\xcf', b'\xa7\xe0\x9b\x8bl\x88\x85,b\x04`3\xe6\x03\x85\x8e'), (b'\xc5\xbf\xd4\xa7\xe7e\xe5\x8a\xe0\xbc\xa8\xb8Yw\x0c\xd3', b":\xc2a\xb6\xd3\x1ct'z\xfe\xf9\xa7P\x8c\x1c\x7f"), (b'\xfd\xb2\x9aP\xc9\x0c\xcf\xe2\x8c\x82g\x8c{r\x94\x84', b'3B\xca\x8c\xd8\x9a\xb8\x94iyT\xd6\x05N_\x8a'), (b'\xea\x7f\x83\xaa\\\x10y\xd1h\x93l\xd9\xfe\x87\xe8j', b'jj\x8f\x1a-tq\xd9\xf1\xf8\xf7\xa5\xf6\x86\xb9\xdb'), (b'\xa4\x0b\x0f\xf1\x84\x95\x1eK\xddtH\xf0IaY:', b'p\xb5\xd9"\xb7\x0f(\r\xb1\x9bm\xc0hq\x00e'), (b'ga\x8f\xbbo\xff\xedQ\x9aM\xbe\x9cTO\xd35', b'=\xc3\x9d\x8d\xd0\xae8*1\x1d\xbf\x84\x89~76'), (b'\xaf\xe1%\xc6\xedo\xec24\xc0\x9d\xa8\x9fy=N', b'\x03m\x81\xd7B\x04\x1a*`C\xee\xccb\x1fm\xf0'), (b'\x1f\x10\xf6\x9fa\xc5\xbf\xaf\x18\xb1Mw\xba\x92&\xe1', b'\xb7\x90/\r$\t\xce}xk\xe7\xbeL\xe9\x8e\xc6'), (b'\xc8.\xd9)\x08g/\xc6\x0e\xed\xbb\xb9\xab\xad\xc8\xa1', b'\xa1c\xcc\xe9\xaasJ\x98\x1d\xd24\xc0\xf2+\x9d\xac'), (b'\xa1\x91\xa0:D\x11(\xb3\xbc0\x13\xd9\xdeD\xb9\x86', b'\x0fV\xa1\x8fl\x0c\xf4\x94=\xe7\xd0*\xdb\xcb\xa5;'), (b'bx;\x8dA\x83\xb8lca\x9c\xadV\xc2\xba/', b'\xe9\xe0\xe7({\x11\r*\xca\xf1\x08\x9bG\x830\x82'), (b"\xde\xbb\xd9\xce{%MP'Xj\xed8>\xa3a", b'\\5M\x13\x13\xb1YY\xa53y\x99$a\x91\xa5'), (b'\xf1\xda\xc4\xfe\xc6\x83\xe6\xf3\xc6\x88\x86H\xc4\x15\x12\xb4', b"\xf8'^\xe5\xb8`\x0fl\x06$\x1cz:\x93\xa1\\"), (b'\xc7@\x03Ny\x11\x96\xcb\xfe\x19\x0e\x18\xbf\xd59I', b'P\xf0\x0f\xec\xaf\x1bS\xa8\x8dt\x11O\xe8\x0f|2'), (b'\xb4\xda\xff\x8c0\x18/\xf1\xad\xa4F\x94\xb1\xad\xf4\xf1', b'.\x83(\x8f#\xe1\x11\x96\xdeS\x17\x8b\xe3]\xb5\xca'), (b'\x1d\t\x11\xc1\x15\xdc\x8e\xea\xe1\xd2\xba%J\\\xf2\xfd', b'\x070ht\xb4\xdeQ+\xc5\xb8#\xac\xd9z\xc0A'), (b' V\xe3\xc5gEg\xc5\xd5\xe1\xd6\xd7\xab\xd0\xb6n', b'\x88\x9b8\xf6\xe26\x92z\x91\xe4\x92\x1e\xbc\xc5;u'), (b'\x88}\xd7*QFn:\xd7\x12RA\xe6-\xd2)', b'\xeb\x04<\xe6\xfa)u\x9ds\xecj\xa7\x84\xcf\xa7\xa7'), (b"\xec\x04.bP)'\xb6\x08\x05\x92\x8c\x85\x1a\x84\x8f", b'@\x80\x08A\xba\x9c2Sd\xdf\x97\x07\xc4Im\xef'), (b'\x11(\x9ez\x0c\xd7\xca+7\xcc\xb0\x19,:\xcb5', b'\xf9V\x8cm\xe5-\xf9\xf1\xf6g\x86~\x8f\xd0<\x84'), (b'\xbb\xe9I=\xc74\xc9C\x0cT\x81\x9d\x85\xdeWF', b'\xfe\x1b\xb1gi\x94O\x98\xf0\x90cJ\xdb\xbf\xc7\x1e'), (b'2`\x9d\x9c\x02\xe4\xce\xf0\x14\xc0Z\xaaW\xf2\xa5\xff', b'\xe6\x05?\xe3X"\xb2O)~\x96\x8f^\x9c\x077'), (b'\xaf\x87,a\xa9\xcd\n|O\x1e\xa7\xdd\xba\x89;\x9d', b'\x98b\xac?\x13*\xf2m\xfeo=v\x96\xd5\x14\x8d'), (b'\xee\xcb{\xeeRQ\x82}\x05|\xc6S\x82\x85\xa4\xff', b'C\x93\xdes\x00\xe8cY<\xde1.\x19\xd8\xe5R'), (b'\xack\x036\x9b4\xca\xa4\x15\xbd\xd5\xbe\xd3\xd4\xfb{', b'm?\xc44>\xf4qig\x10\x8c\xeb\x11o\x99\xb4'), (b'D!\x0e*\xb3/<\x15F_\xd6;j\x85\xbe,', b'Y\xb01H\xb6:\x04_]OL\x9d\x8e\xbcp\xdc'), (b'\xe6\x9d\x02L[\x1c\xee\x8b0lu\xdd\x00\x9a\xfa!', b'J&\tkf\xa8\xeb\x1b\x90\x81\xce\\\x1b\xe8\xb6\x1d'), (b'\xcdnd\xf6\xf6\x11\x9e\x06\x10\xce\xcfP\x89\xed\xad\x02', b'I:\xe0{8H\xfcw\xb1\xe9v\x11p-/0'), (b'\xa22?\xcd\xfbU+\xbf- \xe3<\xc2\x94\xef\xb6', b'\xc7\x89\xc4K?{\x18\x1ftd\x0f\x19L}\xba\xf9'), (b'8\xf9\xe9\xd0\xa0\x97\x8e\rp\xe9\xd6[\x8e`\x93\x81', b'\xf7\x16"\xaa\x86\\b\x9d\x0c\x17"\x81\xeea\x03\x19'), (b')\xfb\x0c\xc7-D\xd8\xa4\xf7\x8d%\x02\x06\xa1\xbf\x94', b'\xc8s!s\xe2n\xee\xb0\x1eC\x15\xc0\xb4d\x08\xa7'), (b'\x7f\xa6\xdc\xf4\x9e\xe3\xda\xd3\x8a\xcb\xfc\x98,1\\\xe5', b'\x82,\xfbKL_\xe9\xc9L`\xc7"&3#\xb5'), (b'&\x98,\x88\xff\x0e\xca[\xcb\xc6t;\xbc5Y"', b'\x1b\x8bA\xd1\x8a\x9e\xe6\xce\xc4#C\x89\xe9Uon'), (b'\x1c\x1b\xac2\x86\xd6\x9a\xf9\xdd\x8d=\xa3\xff\x9a\xe1\xa5', b'\xed\x10\xed\xc1\xfe\xec\xd3\x0b\x8b\xe9\xd4?H"\xd6\x8f'), (b'9\x8f3\x8b\x02\xb7\xe7\xe5\xa1TO\x1a\xb6N\x0b\xb6', b'\xb4\x0f\xa7 \xc7\x83\x81\x18\x9cU\xfd2\x93\xb8(\xe9'), (b'\x8d\xbe\xcf`\xc3d\xde\xca\xf4\n.\x92Mrw\xa6', b';\t\xfb\x19eKt0\x8foG\xcd\xd5\xe0\xf6\x9d'), (b'd\xbcG)\xec\xc8\x04 \xdd\xd9\xf6\xd6\x91/\xb2\xd3', b'2\xba\xa8\x8a\xc5\xd6h\xab\x9c\x9e\x8b\x1b5\xcc_.'), (b'\x98\xea\xf0\xcbJ-c\xea\x81\xcf?B\x17\xcb\x99\xf9', b'\x82\x05\x14\xf2\x05q\x97\xf7Z-B\xad\xa2\x16\xa0`'), (b'\x1c\x94A\xfd\xe1\xf2\x06\x8b\x19\x80\xfa\x01g\xc3V\xaf', b'\x1c\xde\xec\xdf&\x93u\xab\xf9\x12\xfb\x04\xbc0\x99d'), (b'6\xfa\x993b\t\x12E\xd2t\xde\xb6\xfa\x98Im', b',\xa2\xf7VB\x81\x048\xc8\xbf3\xce\x8d\xecn\x82'), (b'L\xd6\x93\xbe\x02\xbeT\xa1\x8d\x88\x84\x18\xc7\xcf\x9fE', b'\x16i"\xb7\x81\xef7\x7f\xdb\x7fY\xbft\x1b\xac\xd0'), (b'\x90\xd6\xe7>Z\x8b\x83\x14\xab\xefH\xa1\x95\xe6\x8e\xc3', b'\xebJ\xfcXd\xd75I@\x12\xe9\x88\xdcG\x15\xb7'), (b'\xb8\xd6\xd03j\xed\xf9\xa0\xb1L3\x8d\x89P\xb4\xe5', b'\xe3\xdf)CR\x03s\x19\x8f\xb5\xc6\xf5\xee&W\xee'), (b'cx\xd7dQ\xc3)YR\x9c7\xf0\xb4\xe4P\xfd', b'h\xa8\x122\xceV\x8c\xf4\x12\x14J\x08\x91\xcf\x93\xfa'), (b'\x1d\x14\x86\xccTi\xdd\xc3L!\x97\x92\xb3\xb7X$', b't\x84\xa4\xe72\xa5X\xe9Ta\x03\x0c\xb00\x07\x83'), (b'\xa6\xdd\x1f\xfc\xca2\x88\x99\xbeA\x9a\xa6JVJ\x84', b'B\x81\x8e-K\xde\x15\xfd\t"\x08\x04@/-\xc9'), (b']b\x18\xe65C\x17*\x103J?\xe79!\x9b', b'\n\xbb\x1f\x98\nZZ\x97\xe0\x12\xf6W\xc4\x1e_~'), (b'\x9a\x9f-c\t\x14\xa4NL\xc5\xc0\x99R\x15\x94\xca', b'\xa0\xf9\x11\xfa\xd7\xf3\xb5\x11\xb2SK\xe8\xdb\x06\x94\x1f'), (b'!\xf0\x90\xd8t_O\xc1\xb5\xfe}\xca\xa6\x15}\x19', b'\xc9+\x89a9y3\xe0\xffh\xedmMq\x13\xcc'), (b'`\xf1\xab\x07A\xe9\xe5\x805\xf2\xabD8\xce\x85A', b'\x9d\x0f\x91\xc2\x01\x93\x8fm\xd6\x03XZl\t\x15J'), (b')\r\xcf\xc0\xa1\xa9\xf7i\x94\xa9\x8d\xed\xea\xcd\xb0B', b'jq\xe9\x01*H\x14\xa7M\x8c\xd2\xa5\x19\\\x80\x12'), (b'vJ\x98\xbf\xd5D\x15\xdb\xa1\xd7\xdc\xaf\xa0\xaa\xf7\xc1', b'\x06\xd8-\x05\xfe\x172W\xa4\xab\xe4\x97_h\xe6\xac'), (b"\xc6'P\xd2\xfcq\xcb\n\xe2\xc1sN>\xbc\x9a\x08", b'\xacysx4z\x96\x8f\xf1\xa5M\x9e\xe7f\\\x16'), (b'\x00\xc6\x81\xf0\xf1\xcb\xa8_\x1fF\x18\xe9\xb0\x95\xa3\xab', b'N\xd8\xdaz\xe8F4\xb1\x88>\xec\xd6[\x15\xd7\xfd'), (b'E\x1ee\x8f\xd5\x0f\x19\xa8\xb6~-\xe0n\xe7\x89\xe1', b'\x83\x90\xa0\x93\xec\x086+\xcf\x08\x9c\x048\x85\x88^'), (b"\x82\x13\xfa\x9f 6\xd3'\xd7\xd2\xc1\xf9\x03.\x13*", b'J\xe2\xf8\x1e\xec\xeb\xd9"q\xbb:\x04\xc2\xdf<\xa8'), (b'\x01\xdf\xfcPW\xc80&{\xfe\x99\xf8\x10\xc6R\xce', b'=Cnh3\x9drKE\x1aU\x8e\xcc\x84jS'), (b'<\xeeo[J\xb0r0N\x07\xf4\x1e\xfb\x16\xac\x07', b'\xf9KP\xfe\xd2\xed\xc7`\xc7\x0c\x9et\xd3^\xc9g'), (b'P\xa1b#\x07V\xb0s\x86S\x9a\x1d[\xd9\xe7\x92', b'r&\xb1a\x0ff2\xd2\x8ft\x13\xff\xba\x0fy\xf4'), (b'\xc8t\xcc\x96V\x8bS\xde\x98\xf1\xa33\xa9\xdb\x1b\x85', b'13\xf1&\x8c\xfe3\xf9\xca\\\xc6\xdb\x1dT\x04b'), (b'\xb9u\xf2O\xfb\x05\xb3\xc2r*\x17d\\\x8f9M', b'\xeeQ\xf9&\xc5\xc8\xc8\xe6B\x1d\xcf\x184\x19]b'), (b'\x96\xe6\xc9\x1e;\x83e4\xb0\xbe\xf6\x94\x03\x06\x85:', b'\xa2\xb0\nS\xaf\xads.\x94\x16s\x901\xaf-\xe4'), (b'&\x81t\x048(\xd7 \xb6\x1aR\xaa\x98\xdbN\x0b', b'\x9cd\x8a#\xdd \xdcS\x14\x1e\x1b\xea\x87\x1b\xa41'), (b"\x1fC\x0cr,\x1d\xab\xa8\xd9\xfc\xa1\xa2\xbb\xcdw'", b'D\xb6)\x7f\xd7\xe6\xb2@\x18D\x1d\x08c\xce2k'), (b'$\xc1\xabD\r\xe0a\x0co\x12\x17\xbdB\x06\xc9y', b's\xd8\xf8\x05\x81\xfeY\xc4\xc8|\xe5\xe2]U\xfa"'), (b'\x8f\xe3\xd6\xc9d\xc4\xf0\xd0\xe3\x17\x12\x82\xb2\xfd\xe9\xef', b'\xf1\r/9\x97/\xd4\xf6dz\x89\x7fEG/\x15'), (b'\x16\xf2\xd8\x9a\x029\x9b{\x02\xf4u\x08~\x80\xb9Z', b'\xe1+:9\xaa\x87:\xf0\x02\xdd\xe5}G\x0ch\x98'), (b'\xe5\n\xf8gP\xfd\x8aT\x04\xf2\xdc\xa4dgcO', b'\x13\xd0\x1c[\xe6\x8aa\xd6\xa0a\xb1X\x84\xb8\xde2'), (b'\xa8\xaa\xa8\xe7\xcal>\xe6\xdb\x18vL\xdak%}', b"\xe5W'\x83\xbd\xf2\x01\x9b\x89\x98l\xfd\xcf\x02\x84\x13"), (b'6\x9b\xae\x07\xe0+\xa0\xcd\xdbT\t\x02@\x81$E', b'\x10Q\x1an\xaa\xe7\x9cy\x04t\x16\x1d\xea\x9d\xd2\xe6'), (b'ne\x83\xb0\xe2\x8aG\xda\xaf%\x93cg\x84\xaf\xea', b'p!}\x8aQ(C\x08\xaf\x8bi\x80\xdaw\x7f\x81'), (b'<\xa6\x90\xb2\x03\x8f\xa4\x17$\xc7\xbe\x8a\x1e!\x01s', b'\x19\x7ftaaLUB\x1aBt\xf5U~\xeeY'), (b'\xe4|z\xaer8\xa0\xa3\xc8\x9c\x8d\x03`\xb8rN', b'b\xda\xf8e\n\x1f\xc1\xb2\x97\x13\xd7\x91\x91\x86\xbe\x13'), (b'\x00\x84\xc1\xd8\xe0ub\x1a\xc0\xa1\xfe\x08K\xfb>,', b'g\xb06$\xbb{s\xb9-\x8e5h|+\xf8\xb1'), (b'(\xac{\xb1^OOy\xc98\xf5\xc5\xc2\xd3\xb3\x1e', b'\x8d\xfc\x0f\xda\xd5\xa6\x89)\x92\x173\x1e)*\xf4&'), (b'G*.\xe2\xd8\xee\x87\xfa\x83~eS\xcc\x1e\xdeQ', b'\xc9y \x1a]Y\x8d\xf8\xa0\xd0^p\xc1\xf1\xa4\xd2'), (b'\x16\x91\xd7[\xbeC\x80T\x08\x0f\xbd\xe1\xf7\xbd\x1b\xb8', b'\xcc\x8c\xfb\x1f"\x16\xa7/\xe2inK\xaa\xdf\xc0\xe4'), (b'\x1d\xbc\xf2\x9b\xe90\x13\xc9\tuuk\r\xe4\xa9\xfa', b'\xf6\x97\xf2B\xaa\x83\xf9k\x15K\xa0\xb9\xdf\xf4,\x02'), (b'hIA(;\x8b\x92G!K\xca\x1a\xfd\x8c9\x95', b'0!V\xfc\xfb\xa1,R\xc6\xdaO\x9c\x16\xa8<\xe2'), (b'?\xd8\xd7e\x88\xad\xcd\xd6\x8d\\\x1e\xc2l$;\xd8', b"\x88\x8e\x86'#f\xcf\xe3,\x96&\r\xb1\xee@g"), (b"\x81\n\x18\xd7\x92\\dv'\x1a\xea\x8c7\xf2S\xb0", b'\x99\xbf\xf9qo\xde\x92xge\x04\x84\xb8 \xfb\xe3'), (b'\xa7\x8d\x83\xc8\xa3\xc15\xdc`\x82\xed\xae.\xea\xf2\xea', b'[\xe8{\r\xd6g\xcf\xe8L\x16\xde\xcd\x90M\xbd\x9e'), (b'\x1a\x1b;\xa62\x10i\xb2\x19n\xc1\xddKz\xb4\xd8', b';On\xd2N\xef%B\x05_T9)IG\xcf'), (b'@g`\x1e\xc1\xdf\x14A\xc1\x04N\xb6]\x97\xd3\x17', b'\xbc6\xcb\xaah*\xf1\xd0_\xd9B\x94F\xa8\xd8\r'), (b'<\x86\xa4z\xb4\xaeS\x90\xa9\xb5I\xe8\xe6FI\x8c', b'\r2\xd2.H"\xfb\x9d}{\x11^\xdf\xcb\x186'), (b'\xf0\xb8J|\x0b\xfe\xcd\x8b\xc0$&"8\xffob', b'\xa8}\xf31\xdd\x07\xc6\xa0\xbb\x9f0\xca\xe3&^\xf6'), (b'r\x9b\x81\xa0D\x94\x80\xfdu\xb1O\xbc\xf6\x1a\xd8\xe0', b'\xd4)\xb6\xdbQ\xa5#\x16\xed9\xadM\xf82%\xeb'), (b'\xb9V\xb7R\xb9\xcdJ9c\x1a`V\xb9\xb0oX', b'\x9a\xff]\xb3\x83\x96\xf5\r\x98\xe2\xc5\x86\xa21k%'), (b"J\xe9\xaa\x8f\x07\xab\x90\x18'\xa6\x85\x08\x18\xa8\x96?", b'\xa7\x83\xed\xd9\t\xd8\x85\xe4\xf8\xcb0\x95n\xf2`\xa8'), (b'\xc3\xaf\xc8m\xfc\x90}=\xb8\x1fr\xab}\r\xc1!', b'\x04\xa0sq\xf7\xd3Dm\xb9\xb8\x9c\xbap(\xa1L'), (b'\x97bq\x0f\x93\xb5\xa1\xa1\xf58\xdcu5\x9a\xbd\x8b', b"\x07'\xc0\xdb/0\xd9H\x81\x06\xe2^ `F\xa9"), (b'Nn\xd4\xbd\x13dN\x9e\xcd\xd4\x06kk~\xf5\x7f', b"\x98j'}\xc5\xb0\x1d\x19\xe2/\x92'\x9e\xd4\xba("), (b'\x08ty\x84\xde>\x0f5jL6\x05\xe1\x02pH', b'0\xb9\xd5\xd40u\x04\xfdK\xe2D\xbc\xddy\xd4\x11')]
def cost(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        start=time.time()
        res=func(*args,**kwargs)
        end=time.time()
        spend=end-start
        print(f"cost:{spend}")
        return res
    return wrapper
@cost
def test(repeat):
    tmp=[*lis*repeat]
    if example.get_list_size()<4000000:

        for it in tmp:
            t=b'something here'
            example.init_map(it[0],t ,16,len(t),int(random.random()*10000))
 
    print(f"pool size is {example.get_list_size()}")
    print(f"get args from lis start")
    print(lis)
    arg1=lis[0][0]
    print(f"get args from lis complete")
    t=b'something need search'
    print(f"start search")
    res=example.search(arg1,t,16,len(t),0.1,int(random.random()*10000))
    l=len(gc.get_objects())
    print(f"res is {len(res)},gc:{l}")


if __name__=='__main__':
    for i in range(10000):
        test(10)
```

error

```bash
pool size is 1000
get args from lis start
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f0ca3c90340 (most recent call first):
  File "/tmp/tmp.ztKz0S1yKb/test.py", line 29 in test
  File "/tmp/tmp.ztKz0S1yKb/test.py", line 12 in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp.ztKz0S1yKb/test.py", line 41 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried using PyMem_RawMalloc and Py_DecRef but still segfault. what should i do?

Sorry for the little misinformation I gave.
I may have located where the problem is:
[problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKulg.png)

Everything works when I comment out Py_DecRef ,otherwise it throws a seg fault exception:

[gdb backtrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gn65.jpg),
[print info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRQ71.png)

I don't understand why Py_DecRef can't be used here.

Comment: Have you used a debugger? What did it tell you?

Comment: Why the header file? If that is a *Python* module, it doesn't have to export anything (*C* style).

Comment: *but it's not clear to me exactly where the problem is.* -- Did you do the obvious thing, and that is to verify that those values you are sending to `PyMem_RawMalloc` are valid?  What about the return values from that function?  Did you check them for NULL?  The first thing you should do is debug and/or log the values you are using in that C++ function.  Right now, it seems you aren't doing either one (debugging or logging).

Comment: At the top of your cpp file, `#include <cassert>`, then `assert(statement)` every statement that could possibly be in doubt. Build without optimizations and try again - rather than a segfault, you are likely to get an assert firing, with a much more useful message (because you wrote it yourself).

Comment: @CristiFati  ,Thanks for the reminder, I'll fix this question.

Comment: I added some error messages and what might be the problem.

Comment: @MattDMo   The error message indicates that an error occurred in [test.py]:func test while get the arguments for example.search. It was unable to get the list element.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  The error did not appear on the PyMem_RawMalloc. It seems that it appeared on the Py_DecRef or dealloc. However, I will add some valid checks for PyMem_Malloc. Thanks.

Comment: You're freeing *tmp\_b* and *tmp\_c* while their addresses are still referenced in the map. That's clearly recipe for disaster.

Comment: Neither *C*,. nor *Python* code "compiles" *OOTB*. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things wrong:

- *C* and *Python* code have errors, so it doesn't compile / run - not an *MCVE* ([[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))
- There is a mix of raw (*malloc*) and *pymalloc* memory functions
- Mismatches between types and format specifiers
- *C* *API* misunderstanding. According to [[Python.Docs]: Parsing arguments and building values](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#parsing-arguments-and-building-values) (**emphasis** is mine):

  > Note that any Python object references which are provided to the caller are *borrowed* references; **do not decrement their reference count!**
- Design flaw mixing *C* and *Python* types. There is the *C* list that is supposed to be the backbone, but it's tightly coupled with *Python* structures. Also attempting to export the functions from the *.dll* makes me think that things are not very clear for the *OP*. I'd suggest to keep the core functionality at the *C* level and provide wrappers for interacting with *Python*. Otherwise, keep switching from one to another would lose the speed advantage (which I assume is the reason for not writing everything in *Python*)
- The question is tagged *C++*, but there's nothing *C++*'y about the code, it's rather *C* (in *C++* there is *std::list*, smart pointers and other features that could save writing a lot of code)
- Minor ones:

  - *LISTNODE* - *NODE* nesting. Although it looks better structured, the overhead for working with nested structures might be a greater loss
  - Passing the size of *bytes* (which is held inside it)
  - Method arguments specifications
  - Code style
  - Many many others

Before going further, I suggest a thorough reading of the following (including referenced *URL*s):

- [[Python.Docs]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c)
- [[Python.PEPs]: Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html)

Now, there are multiple problems, each with multiple solutions.
Starting from your code, I prepared an example. It's written in *C* (lots of code which doesn't have anything to do with the goal).
All the business logic is carried out in *C* (it's callable from a *C* application), and the *Python* wrapping layer is on top of that.

- *dll00.h*:

  ```c
  #include <stdint.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(PY_MOD_BUILD)
  #  if defined(DLL00_STATIC)
  #    define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined DLL00_EXPORTS
  #      define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  typedef uint8_t byte;
  typedef unsigned long ulong;

  typedef struct Node_ {
      byte *features;
      ulong features_len;
      char *content;
      ulong content_len;
      long id;

      struct Node_ *next;
  } Node, *PNode;

  typedef struct {
      size_t len;
      PNode *nodes;
      double *scores;
  } FoundData, *PFoundData;


  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API int addNode(const byte *features, ulong features_len, const char *content, ulong content_len, long id);
  DLL00_EXPORT_API size_t size();
  DLL00_EXPORT_API PFoundData search(const byte *features, ulong features_len, const char *content, ulong content_len, long id, double threshold);
  DLL00_EXPORT_API void freeFoundData(PFoundData data, int membersOnly);
  DLL00_EXPORT_API size_t cleanup();

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif
  ```
- *dll00.c*:

  ```c
  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #define DLL00_EXPORTS
  #include "dll00.h"


  static Node *gHead = NULL;
  static Node *gCur = NULL;
  static size_t gLen = 0;


  int addNode(const byte *features, ulong features_len, const char *content, ulong content_len, long id)
  {
      Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      if (node == NULL) {
          return -1;
      }
      node->features = malloc(sizeof(byte) * features_len);
      if (node->features == NULL) {
          free(node);
          return -2;
      }
      node->content = malloc(sizeof(char) * content_len);
      if (node->content == NULL) {
          free(node->features);
          free(node);
          return -3;
      }
      memcpy(node->features, features, features_len);
      node->features_len = features_len;
      memcpy(node->content, content, content_len);
      node->content_len = content_len;
      node->id = id;
      node->next = NULL;
      if (gCur == NULL) {
          gCur = node;
          gHead = node;
      } else {
          gCur->next = node;
          gCur = node;
      }
      ++gLen;
      return 0;
  }


  size_t size()
  {
      return gLen;
  }


  static double compare(const byte *features0, ulong features0_len, const byte *features1, ulong features1_len, int min)
  {
      // @TODO - cfati: Dumb comparison
      if ((features0_len > 1) && (features1_len > 1) && ((features0[0] == features1[0]) || (features0[0] == features1[1]) || (features0[1] == features1[0]) || (features0[1] == features1[1]))) {
          return 0.3;
      }
      return 0;
  }


  PFoundData search(const byte *features, ulong features_len, const char *content, ulong content_len, long id, double threshold)
  {
      if (gCur == NULL) {
          return NULL;
      }
      Node *node = gHead;
      FoundData tmp = {0, NULL, NULL};
      tmp.nodes = malloc(sizeof(PNode) * gLen);
      if (tmp.nodes == NULL) {
          perror("malloc failed 1.");
          freeFoundData(&tmp, 1);
          return NULL;
      }
      tmp.scores = malloc(sizeof(double) * gLen);
      if (tmp.scores == NULL) {
          perror("malloc failed 2.");
          freeFoundData(&tmp, 1);
          return NULL;
      }
      while (node != NULL) {
          double score = compare(features, features_len, node->features, node->features_len, 0);
          if (score > threshold) {
              tmp.nodes[tmp.len] = node;
              tmp.scores[tmp.len] = score;
              ++tmp.len;
          }
          node = node->next;
      }
      if (tmp.len == 0) {
          return NULL;
      } else {
          PFoundData ret = calloc(1, sizeof(FoundData));
          if (ret == NULL) {
              perror("malloc failed 3.");
              freeFoundData(&tmp, 1);
              return NULL;
          }
          ret->nodes = malloc(sizeof(PNode) * tmp.len);
          if (ret->nodes == NULL) {
              perror("malloc failed 4.");
              freeFoundData(ret, 0);
              freeFoundData(&tmp, 1);
              return NULL;
          }
          ret->scores = malloc(sizeof(double) * tmp.len);
          if (ret->scores == NULL) {
              perror("malloc failed 5.");
              freeFoundData(ret, 0);
              freeFoundData(&tmp, 1);
              return NULL;
          }
          ret->len = tmp.len;
          memcpy(ret->nodes, tmp.nodes, sizeof(PNode) * tmp.len);
          memcpy(ret->scores, tmp.scores, sizeof(double) * tmp.len);
          freeFoundData(&tmp, 1);
          return ret;
      }
  }


  void freeFoundData(PFoundData data, int membersOnly)
  {
      if (data == NULL)
          return;
      free(data->nodes);
      free(data->scores);
      if (!membersOnly)
          free(data);
  }


  size_t cleanup()
  {
      size_t ret = 0;
      Node *node = gHead;
      while (node != NULL) {
          free(node->features);
          free(node->content);
          Node *next = node->next;
          free(node);
          node = next;
          ++ret;
      }
      gHead = NULL;
      gCur = NULL;
      gLen = 0;
      return ret;
  }
  ```
- *main00.c*:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include "dll00.h"


  void handleFoundData(PFoundData data)
  {
      printf("Found data (%d items):\n", data == NULL ? 0 : data->len);
      if (data == NULL)
          return;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < data->len; ++i) {
          printf(" Index: %d\n  Score: %.03f\n", i, data->scores[i]);
          printf("  Id: %d, Features length: %d, Content length: %d\n", data->nodes[i]->id, data->nodes[i]->features_len, data->nodes[i]->content_len);
          printf("  Feats: %s\n", data->nodes[i]->features);
          printf("  Cnt: %s\n", data->nodes[i]->content);
      }
      freeFoundData(data, 0);
  }


  int main()
  {
      Node dummies[] = {
          {"1\02", 3, "567\0890", 7, 2},
          {"ab\0c", 4, "d4567\0890", 9, 3},
      };
      printf("Element count: %zu\n", size());
      for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dummies) / sizeof(dummies[0]); ++i)
          printf("Add node (%d) returned: %d\n", i, addNode(dummies[i].features, dummies[i].features_len, dummies[i].content, dummies[i].content_len, dummies[i].id));
      printf("Element count: %zu\n", size());
      // @TODO - cfati: Values based on .dll's dumb comparison
      byte *src[] = {
          "xxx",  // None
          "111",  // 1st
          "xaa",  // 2nd
          "1bd",  // Both
      };
      for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(src) / sizeof(src[0]); ++i) {
          printf("Search for '%s' ...\n", src[i]);
          PFoundData found = search(src[i], strlen(src[i]), "", 0, 0, 0.1);
          handleFoundData(found);
      }
      printf("Freed %zu nodes\n", cleanup());
      printf("Element count: %zu\n", size());
      printf("\nDone.\n\n");
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *example.c*:

  ```c
  #define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
  #include <Python.h>

  //#define PY_MOD_BUILD
  #include "dll00.h"

  #define MOD_NAME "_example"


  static PyObject* example_size(PyObject *self, PyObject *Py_UNUSED(args))
  {
      return PyLong_FromSize_t(size());
  }


  static PyObject* example_add_node(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
  {
      PyObject *feat = NULL, *cnt = NULL;
      long id;
      if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "SSl", &feat, &cnt, &id)) {
          return NULL;
      }
      int ret = addNode((const byte*)PyBytes_AsString(feat), (ulong)PyBytes_Size(feat), PyBytes_AsString(cnt), (ulong)PyBytes_Size(cnt), id);
      return PyLong_FromLong(ret);
  }


  static PyObject* example_search(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
  {
      PyObject *feat = NULL, *cnt = NULL;
      long id;
      double thres;
      if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "SSld", &feat, &cnt, &id, &thres)) {
          return NULL;
      }
      PFoundData tmp = search((const byte*)PyBytes_AsString(feat), PyBytes_Size(feat), PyBytes_AsString(cnt), PyBytes_Size(cnt), id, thres);
      if (tmp == NULL) {
          return PyList_New(0);
      } else {
          PyObject *ret = PyList_New(tmp->len);
          if (ret == NULL) {
              freeFoundData(tmp, 0);
              return NULL;
          }
          for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp->len; ++i) {
              PyObject *tup = Py_BuildValue(
                  "(ly#y#d)", 
                  tmp->nodes[i]->id,
                  tmp->nodes[i]->content,
                  tmp->nodes[i]->content_len,
                  tmp->nodes[i]->features,
                  tmp->nodes[i]->features_len,
                  tmp->scores[i]);
                  // @TODO - cfati: No need to include data passed in arguments in each of the output tuples !!!
              if (tup == NULL) {
                  Py_XDECREF(ret);
                  freeFoundData(tmp, 0);
                  return NULL;
              } else {
                  PyList_SET_ITEM(ret, i, tup);
              }
          }
          freeFoundData(tmp, 0);
          return ret;
      }
  }


  static PyObject* example_cleanup(PyObject *self, PyObject *Py_UNUSED(args))
  {
      size_t ret = 0;
      //Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
      ret = cleanup();
      //Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
      return PyLong_FromSize_t(ret);
  }


  static PyMethodDef methDef[] = {
      {"size", example_size, METH_NOARGS, "Get List size"},
      {"add_node", example_add_node, METH_VARARGS, "Add node"},
      {"search", example_search, METH_VARARGS, "Search elements"},
      {"cleanup", example_cleanup, METH_NOARGS, "Clean up"},
      {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL},
  };


  static struct PyModuleDef modDef = {
          PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
          MOD_NAME,  // name
          "A module that imports an API",  // Doc string (may be NULL)
          -1,  // Size of per-interpreter state or -1
          methDef,  // Method table
  };


  PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit__example() {
      PyObject *m;

      m = PyModule_Create(&modDef);
      if (m == NULL)
          return NULL;

      /* Import sample, loading its API functions */
      return m;
  }
  ```
- *setup.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  from distutils.core import setup, Extension


  setup(
      name="example",
      ext_modules=[
          Extension("_example",
                    ["example.c", "dll00.c"],
                    include_dirs=(),
                    define_macros=[
                      ("PY_MOD_BUILD", None),
                    ],
          ),
      ],
      version="0.0.1",
  )
  ```
- *data.py* (I just extracted input data to avoid polluting the other source file):

  ```py
  data = [
      (b"\xd3\nR\x952\xbf\x8e\xeb[\xdc\xe8\xfb\xcb\x9f\xb4\xd2", b"\x856\x96\xda\xe4H_\xf9\xb3\x95\xff\xda\xc9\x05\x17\xd5"),
      # @TODO - cfati: !!! DELETED NEXT 20 TUPLES so the answer fits the 30K characters limit !!!
      (b"\xb4\xda\xff\x8c0\x18/\xf1\xad\xa4F\x94\xb1\xad\xf4\xf1", b".\x83(\x8f#\xe1\x11\x96\xdeS\x17\x8b\xe3]\xb5\xca"),
      (b"\x1d\t\x11\xc1\x15\xdc\x8e\xea\xe1\xd2\xba%J\\\xf2\xfd", b"\x070ht\xb4\xdeQ+\xc5\xb8#\xac\xd9z\xc0A"),
      (b" V\xe3\xc5gEg\xc5\xd5\xe1\xd6\xd7\xab\xd0\xb6n", b"\x88\x9b8\xf6\xe26\x92z\x91\xe4\x92\x1e\xbc\xc5;u"),
      (b"\x88}\xd7*QFn:\xd7\x12RA\xe6-\xd2)", b"\xeb\x04<\xe6\xfa)u\x9ds\xecj\xa7\x84\xcf\xa7\xa7"),
      (b"\xec\x04.bP)'\xb6\x08\x05\x92\x8c\x85\x1a\x84\x8f", b"@\x80\x08A\xba\x9c2Sd\xdf\x97\x07\xc4Im\xef"),
      (b"\x11(\x9ez\x0c\xd7\xca+7\xcc\xb0\x19,:\xcb5", b"\xf9V\x8cm\xe5-\xf9\xf1\xf6g\x86~\x8f\xd0<\x84"),
      (b"\xbb\xe9I=\xc74\xc9C\x0cT\x81\x9d\x85\xdeWF", b"\xfe\x1b\xb1gi\x94O\x98\xf0\x90cJ\xdb\xbf\xc7\x1e"),
      (b"2`\x9d\x9c\x02\xe4\xce\xf0\x14\xc0Z\xaaW\xf2\xa5\xff", b"\xe6\x05?\xe3X\"\xb2O)~\x96\x8f^\x9c\x077"),
      (b"\xaf\x87,a\xa9\xcd\n|O\x1e\xa7\xdd\xba\x89;\x9d", b"\x98b\xac?\x13*\xf2m\xfeo=v\x96\xd5\x14\x8d"),
      (b"\xee\xcb{\xeeRQ\x82}\x05|\xc6S\x82\x85\xa4\xff", b"C\x93\xdes\x00\xe8cY<\xde1.\x19\xd8\xe5R"),
      (b"\xack\x036\x9b4\xca\xa4\x15\xbd\xd5\xbe\xd3\xd4\xfb{", b"m?\xc44>\xf4qig\x10\x8c\xeb\x11o\x99\xb4"),
      (b"D!\x0e*\xb3/<\x15F_\xd6;j\x85\xbe,", b"Y\xb01H\xb6:\x04_]OL\x9d\x8e\xbcp\xdc"),
      (b"\xe6\x9d\x02L[\x1c\xee\x8b0lu\xdd\x00\x9a\xfa!", b"J&\tkf\xa8\xeb\x1b\x90\x81\xce\\\x1b\xe8\xb6\x1d"),
      (b"\xcdnd\xf6\xf6\x11\x9e\x06\x10\xce\xcfP\x89\xed\xad\x02", b"I:\xe0{8H\xfcw\xb1\xe9v\x11p-/0"),
      (b"\xa22?\xcd\xfbU+\xbf- \xe3<\xc2\x94\xef\xb6", b"\xc7\x89\xc4K?{\x18\x1ftd\x0f\x19L}\xba\xf9"),
      (b"8\xf9\xe9\xd0\xa0\x97\x8e\rp\xe9\xd6[\x8e`\x93\x81", b"\xf7\x16\"\xaa\x86\\b\x9d\x0c\x17\"\x81\xeea\x03\x19"),
      (b")\xfb\x0c\xc7-D\xd8\xa4\xf7\x8d%\x02\x06\xa1\xbf\x94", b"\xc8s!s\xe2n\xee\xb0\x1eC\x15\xc0\xb4d\x08\xa7"),
      (b"\x7f\xa6\xdc\xf4\x9e\xe3\xda\xd3\x8a\xcb\xfc\x98,1\\\xe5", b"\x82,\xfbKL_\xe9\xc9L`\xc7\"&3#\xb5"),
      (b"&\x98,\x88\xff\x0e\xca[\xcb\xc6t;\xbc5Y\"", b"\x1b\x8bA\xd1\x8a\x9e\xe6\xce\xc4#C\x89\xe9Uon"),
      (b"\x1c\x1b\xac2\x86\xd6\x9a\xf9\xdd\x8d=\xa3\xff\x9a\xe1\xa5", b"\xed\x10\xed\xc1\xfe\xec\xd3\x0b\x8b\xe9\xd4?H\"\xd6\x8f"),
      (b"9\x8f3\x8b\x02\xb7\xe7\xe5\xa1TO\x1a\xb6N\x0b\xb6", b"\xb4\x0f\xa7 \xc7\x83\x81\x18\x9cU\xfd2\x93\xb8(\xe9"),
      (b"\x8d\xbe\xcf`\xc3d\xde\xca\xf4\n.\x92Mrw\xa6", b";\t\xfb\x19eKt0\x8foG\xcd\xd5\xe0\xf6\x9d"),
      (b"d\xbcG)\xec\xc8\x04 \xdd\xd9\xf6\xd6\x91/\xb2\xd3", b"2\xba\xa8\x8a\xc5\xd6h\xab\x9c\x9e\x8b\x1b5\xcc_."),
      (b"\x98\xea\xf0\xcbJ-c\xea\x81\xcf?B\x17\xcb\x99\xf9", b"\x82\x05\x14\xf2\x05q\x97\xf7Z-B\xad\xa2\x16\xa0`"),
      (b"\x1c\x94A\xfd\xe1\xf2\x06\x8b\x19\x80\xfa\x01g\xc3V\xaf", b"\x1c\xde\xec\xdf&\x93u\xab\xf9\x12\xfb\x04\xbc0\x99d"),
      (b"6\xfa\x993b\t\x12E\xd2t\xde\xb6\xfa\x98Im", b",\xa2\xf7VB\x81\x048\xc8\xbf3\xce\x8d\xecn\x82"),
      (b"L\xd6\x93\xbe\x02\xbeT\xa1\x8d\x88\x84\x18\xc7\xcf\x9fE", b"\x16i\"\xb7\x81\xef7\x7f\xdb\x7fY\xbft\x1b\xac\xd0"),
      (b"\x90\xd6\xe7>Z\x8b\x83\x14\xab\xefH\xa1\x95\xe6\x8e\xc3", b"\xebJ\xfcXd\xd75I@\x12\xe9\x88\xdcG\x15\xb7"),
      (b"\xb8\xd6\xd03j\xed\xf9\xa0\xb1L3\x8d\x89P\xb4\xe5", b"\xe3\xdf)CR\x03s\x19\x8f\xb5\xc6\xf5\xee&W\xee"),
      (b"cx\xd7dQ\xc3)YR\x9c7\xf0\xb4\xe4P\xfd", b"h\xa8\x122\xceV\x8c\xf4\x12\x14J\x08\x91\xcf\x93\xfa"),
      (b"\x1d\x14\x86\xccTi\xdd\xc3L!\x97\x92\xb3\xb7X$", b"t\x84\xa4\xe72\xa5X\xe9Ta\x03\x0c\xb00\x07\x83"),
      (b"\xa6\xdd\x1f\xfc\xca2\x88\x99\xbeA\x9a\xa6JVJ\x84", b"B\x81\x8e-K\xde\x15\xfd\t\"\x08\x04@/-\xc9"),
      (b"]b\x18\xe65C\x17*\x103J?\xe79!\x9b", b"\n\xbb\x1f\x98\nZZ\x97\xe0\x12\xf6W\xc4\x1e_~"),
      (b"\x9a\x9f-c\t\x14\xa4NL\xc5\xc0\x99R\x15\x94\xca", b"\xa0\xf9\x11\xfa\xd7\xf3\xb5\x11\xb2SK\xe8\xdb\x06\x94\x1f"),
      (b"!\xf0\x90\xd8t_O\xc1\xb5\xfe}\xca\xa6\x15}\x19", b"\xc9+\x89a9y3\xe0\xffh\xedmMq\x13\xcc"),
      (b"`\xf1\xab\x07A\xe9\xe5\x805\xf2\xabD8\xce\x85A", b"\x9d\x0f\x91\xc2\x01\x93\x8fm\xd6\x03XZl\t\x15J"),
      (b")\r\xcf\xc0\xa1\xa9\xf7i\x94\xa9\x8d\xed\xea\xcd\xb0B", b"jq\xe9\x01*H\x14\xa7M\x8c\xd2\xa5\x19\\\x80\x12"),
      (b"vJ\x98\xbf\xd5D\x15\xdb\xa1\xd7\xdc\xaf\xa0\xaa\xf7\xc1", b"\x06\xd8-\x05\xfe\x172W\xa4\xab\xe4\x97_h\xe6\xac"),
      (b"\xc6'P\xd2\xfcq\xcb\n\xe2\xc1sN>\xbc\x9a\x08", b"\xacysx4z\x96\x8f\xf1\xa5M\x9e\xe7f\\\x16"),
      (b"\x00\xc6\x81\xf0\xf1\xcb\xa8_\x1fF\x18\xe9\xb0\x95\xa3\xab", b"N\xd8\xdaz\xe8F4\xb1\x88>\xec\xd6[\x15\xd7\xfd"),
      (b"E\x1ee\x8f\xd5\x0f\x19\xa8\xb6~-\xe0n\xe7\x89\xe1", b"\x83\x90\xa0\x93\xec\x086+\xcf\x08\x9c\x048\x85\x88^"),
      (b"\x82\x13\xfa\x9f 6\xd3'\xd7\xd2\xc1\xf9\x03.\x13*", b"J\xe2\xf8\x1e\xec\xeb\xd9\"q\xbb:\x04\xc2\xdf<\xa8"),
      (b"\x01\xdf\xfcPW\xc80&{\xfe\x99\xf8\x10\xc6R\xce", b"=Cnh3\x9drKE\x1aU\x8e\xcc\x84jS"),
      (b"<\xeeo[J\xb0r0N\x07\xf4\x1e\xfb\x16\xac\x07", b"\xf9KP\xfe\xd2\xed\xc7`\xc7\x0c\x9et\xd3^\xc9g"),
      (b"P\xa1b#\x07V\xb0s\x86S\x9a\x1d[\xd9\xe7\x92", b"r&\xb1a\x0ff2\xd2\x8ft\x13\xff\xba\x0fy\xf4"),
      (b"\xc8t\xcc\x96V\x8bS\xde\x98\xf1\xa33\xa9\xdb\x1b\x85", b"13\xf1&\x8c\xfe3\xf9\xca\\\xc6\xdb\x1dT\x04b"),
      (b"\xb9u\xf2O\xfb\x05\xb3\xc2r*\x17d\\\x8f9M", b"\xeeQ\xf9&\xc5\xc8\xc8\xe6B\x1d\xcf\x184\x19]b"),
      (b"\x96\xe6\xc9\x1e;\x83e4\xb0\xbe\xf6\x94\x03\x06\x85:", b"\xa2\xb0\nS\xaf\xads.\x94\x16s\x901\xaf-\xe4"),
      (b"&\x81t\x048(\xd7 \xb6\x1aR\xaa\x98\xdbN\x0b", b"\x9cd\x8a#\xdd \xdcS\x14\x1e\x1b\xea\x87\x1b\xa41"),
      (b"\x1fC\x0cr,\x1d\xab\xa8\xd9\xfc\xa1\xa2\xbb\xcdw'", b"D\xb6)\x7f\xd7\xe6\xb2@\x18D\x1d\x08c\xce2k"),
      (b"$\xc1\xabD\r\xe0a\x0co\x12\x17\xbdB\x06\xc9y", b"s\xd8\xf8\x05\x81\xfeY\xc4\xc8|\xe5\xe2]U\xfa"),
      (b"\x8f\xe3\xd6\xc9d\xc4\xf0\xd0\xe3\x17\x12\x82\xb2\xfd\xe9\xef", b"\xf1\r/9\x97/\xd4\xf6dz\x89\x7fEG/\x15"),
      (b"\x16\xf2\xd8\x9a\x029\x9b{\x02\xf4u\x08~\x80\xb9Z", b"\xe1+:9\xaa\x87:\xf0\x02\xdd\xe5}G\x0ch\x98"),
      (b"\xe5\n\xf8gP\xfd\x8aT\x04\xf2\xdc\xa4dgcO", b"\x13\xd0\x1c[\xe6\x8aa\xd6\xa0a\xb1X\x84\xb8\xde2"),
      (b"\xa8\xaa\xa8\xe7\xcal>\xe6\xdb\x18vL\xdak%}", b"\xe5W'\x83\xbd\xf2\x01\x9b\x89\x98l\xfd\xcf\x02\x84\x13"),
      (b"6\x9b\xae\x07\xe0+\xa0\xcd\xdbT\t\x02@\x81$E", b"\x10Q\x1an\xaa\xe7\x9cy\x04t\x16\x1d\xea\x9d\xd2\xe6"),
      (b"ne\x83\xb0\xe2\x8aG\xda\xaf%\x93cg\x84\xaf\xea", b"p!}\x8aQ(C\x08\xaf\x8bi\x80\xdaw\x7f\x81"),
      (b"<\xa6\x90\xb2\x03\x8f\xa4\x17$\xc7\xbe\x8a\x1e!\x01s", b"\x19\x7ftaaLUB\x1aBt\xf5U~\xeeY"),
      (b"\xe4|z\xaer8\xa0\xa3\xc8\x9c\x8d\x03`\xb8rN", b"b\xda\xf8e\n\x1f\xc1\xb2\x97\x13\xd7\x91\x91\x86\xbe\x13"),
      (b"\x00\x84\xc1\xd8\xe0ub\x1a\xc0\xa1\xfe\x08K\xfb>,", b"g\xb06$\xbb{s\xb9-\x8e5h|+\xf8\xb1"),
      (b"(\xac{\xb1^OOy\xc98\xf5\xc5\xc2\xd3\xb3\x1e", b"\x8d\xfc\x0f\xda\xd5\xa6\x89)\x92\x173\x1e)*\xf4&"),
      (b"G*.\xe2\xd8\xee\x87\xfa\x83~eS\xcc\x1e\xdeQ", b"\xc9y \x1a]Y\x8d\xf8\xa0\xd0^p\xc1\xf1\xa4\xd2"),
      (b"\x16\x91\xd7[\xbeC\x80T\x08\x0f\xbd\xe1\xf7\xbd\x1b\xb8", b"\xcc\x8c\xfb\x1f\"\x16\xa7/\xe2inK\xaa\xdf\xc0\xe4"),
      (b"\x1d\xbc\xf2\x9b\xe90\x13\xc9\tuuk\r\xe4\xa9\xfa", b"\xf6\x97\xf2B\xaa\x83\xf9k\x15K\xa0\xb9\xdf\xf4,\x02"),
      (b"hIA(;\x8b\x92G!K\xca\x1a\xfd\x8c9\x95", b"0!V\xfc\xfb\xa1,R\xc6\xdaO\x9c\x16\xa8<\xe2"),
      (b"?\xd8\xd7e\x88\xad\xcd\xd6\x8d\\\x1e\xc2l$;\xd8", b"\x88\x8e\x86'#f\xcf\xe3,\x96&\r\xb1\xee@g"),
      (b"\x81\n\x18\xd7\x92\\dv'\x1a\xea\x8c7\xf2S\xb0", b"\x99\xbf\xf9qo\xde\x92xge\x04\x84\xb8 \xfb\xe3"),
      (b"\xa7\x8d\x83\xc8\xa3\xc15\xdc`\x82\xed\xae.\xea\xf2\xea", b"[\xe8{\r\xd6g\xcf\xe8L\x16\xde\xcd\x90M\xbd\x9e"),
      (b"\x1a\x1b;\xa62\x10i\xb2\x19n\xc1\xddKz\xb4\xd8", b";On\xd2N\xef%B\x05_T9)IG\xcf"),
      (b"@g`\x1e\xc1\xdf\x14A\xc1\x04N\xb6]\x97\xd3\x17", b"\xbc6\xcb\xaah*\xf1\xd0_\xd9B\x94F\xa8\xd8\r"),
      (b"<\x86\xa4z\xb4\xaeS\x90\xa9\xb5I\xe8\xe6FI\x8c", b"\r2\xd2.H\"\xfb\x9d}{\x11^\xdf\xcb\x186"),
      (b"\xf0\xb8J|\x0b\xfe\xcd\x8b\xc0$&\"8\xffob", b"\xa8}\xf31\xdd\x07\xc6\xa0\xbb\x9f0\xca\xe3&^\xf6"),
      (b"r\x9b\x81\xa0D\x94\x80\xfdu\xb1O\xbc\xf6\x1a\xd8\xe0", b"\xd4)\xb6\xdbQ\xa5#\x16\xed9\xadM\xf82%\xeb"),
      (b"\xb9V\xb7R\xb9\xcdJ9c\x1a`V\xb9\xb0oX", b"\x9a\xff]\xb3\x83\x96\xf5\r\x98\xe2\xc5\x86\xa21k%"),
      (b"J\xe9\xaa\x8f\x07\xab\x90\x18'\xa6\x85\x08\x18\xa8\x96?", b"\xa7\x83\xed\xd9\t\xd8\x85\xe4\xf8\xcb0\x95n\xf2`\xa8"),
      (b"\xc3\xaf\xc8m\xfc\x90}=\xb8\x1fr\xab}\r\xc1!", b"\x04\xa0sq\xf7\xd3Dm\xb9\xb8\x9c\xbap(\xa1L"),
      (b"\x97bq\x0f\x93\xb5\xa1\xa1\xf58\xdcu5\x9a\xbd\x8b", b"\x07'\xc0\xdb/0\xd9H\x81\x06\xe2^ `F\xa9"),
      (b"Nn\xd4\xbd\x13dN\x9e\xcd\xd4\x06kk~\xf5\x7f", b"\x98j'}\xc5\xb0\x1d\x19\xe2/\x92'\x9e\xd4\xba("),
      (b"\x08ty\x84\xde>\x0f5jL6\x05\xe1\x02pH", b"0\xb9\xd5\xd40u\x04\xfdK\xe2D\xbc\xddy\xd4\x11"),
  ]
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import gc
  import random
  import sys
  from pprint import pprint as pp

  import _example as ex
  from data import data


  def test(repeat):
      tmp = data * repeat
      if ex.size() < 4000000:
          for idx, it in enumerate(tmp):
              t = f"dummy content {idx}"
              ex.add_node(it[0], t.encode(), random.randint(0, 10000))

      print(f"List (internal) size: {ex.size()}")
      print(f"Input data len: {len(data)}")
      search_feat = data[0][0]
      t = b"\xd3 "
      print("Start search:")
      res = ex.search(search_feat, t, random.randint(0, 10000), 0.1)
      pp(res)
      print(f"GC len: {len(gc.get_objects())}")


  def main(*argv):
      test(1)
      print(f"List (internal) size: {ex.size()}")
      print(f"Freed {ex.cleanup()} elements")
      print(f"List (internal) size: {ex.size()}")
      print(f"GC len: {len(gc.get_objects())}")


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Outputs**:

- *Win* (*C* *.dll* called from a *C* *.exe*):

  > ```bat
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076229579]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> dir /b
  > code00.py
  > data.py
  > dll00.c
  > dll00.h
  > example.c
  > main00.c
  > orig
  > setup.py
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
  > dll00.c
  >    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
  >
  > [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:win_main00.exe dll00.lib
  > main00.c
  >
  > [prompt]> del *.obj *.exp
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b
  > code00.py
  > data.py
  > dll00.c
  > dll00.dll
  > dll00.h
  > dll00.lib
  > example.c
  > main00.c
  > orig
  > setup.py
  > win_main00.exe
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> win_main00.exe
  > Element count: 0
  > Add node (0) returned: 0
  > Add node (1) returned: 0
  > Element count: 2
  > Search for 'xxx' ...
  > Found data (0 items):
  > Search for '111' ...
  > Found data (1 items):
  >  Index: 0
  >   Score: 0.300
  >   Id: 2, Features length: 3, Content length: 7
  >   Feats: 1?
  >   Cnt: 567
  > Search for 'xaa' ...
  > Found data (1 items):
  >  Index: 0
  >   Score: 0.300
  >   Id: 3, Features length: 4, Content length: 9
  >   Feats: ab
  >   Cnt: d4567
  > Search for '1bd' ...
  > Found data (2 items):
  >  Index: 0
  >   Score: 0.300
  >   Id: 2, Features length: 3, Content length: 7
  >   Feats: 1?
  >   Cnt: 567
  >  Index: 1
  >   Score: 0.300
  >   Id: 3, Features length: 4, Content length: 9
  >   Feats: ab
  >   Cnt: d4567
  > Freed 2 nodes
  > Element count: 0
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Nix* (*Python* module):

  > ```bash
  > (py_pc064_03.10_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076229579]> ~/sopr.sh
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> ls
  > code00.py  data.py  dll00.c  dll00.dll  dll00.h  dll00.lib  example.c  main00.c  orig  setup.py  win_main00.exe
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> python setup.py build
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> ls
  > build  code00.py  data.py  dll00.c  dll00.dll  dll00.h  dll00.lib  example.c  main00.c  orig  setup.py  win_main00.exe
  > [064bit prompt]> ls build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/
  > _example.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310 python code00.py
  > Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:10) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
  >
  > List (internal) size: 100
  > Input data len: 100
  > Start search:
  > [(4555,
  >   b'dummy content 0',
  >   b'\xd3\nR\x952\xbf\x8e\xeb[\xdc\xe8\xfb\xcb\x9f\xb4\xd2',
  >   0.3),
  >  (273, b'dummy content 74', b'\xe5\n\xf8gP\xfd\x8aT\x04\xf2\xdc\xa4dgcO', 0.3),
  >  (9201,
  >   b'dummy content 87',
  >   b"\x81\n\x18\xd7\x92\\dv'\x1a\xea\x8c7\xf2S\xb0",
  >   0.3)]
  > GC len: 8942
  > List (internal) size: 100
  > Freed 100 elements
  > List (internal) size: 0
  > GC len: 8937
  >
  > Done.
  > ```

Comment: Yeah,the most critical issue is the incorrect decrementing of the reference count and the combination of malloc and pymalloc. Your code has provided me with invaluable insights into nested struct overhead and the importance of separating core processing from wrapping. Thank you for your answer!